# hovering not working on div

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, hover

I am trying to apply a hover effect on a div. Why isn't this working at all?

My Html looks like this:

```
<a href="#panel-866" id="panel-866">
  <div class="application-icon" style="background-image: url('/custom-icon-off.png')">
&nbsp;</div>
</a>
```

CSS

```
.tab-title > #panel-866 .application-icon:hover {
    background-image:url(/custom-icon-hover.png);
}
```

Comment: Do you have an image with the name custom-icon-hover.png in your root directory? (check the network tab in browser to see that it's loading/found). Is `#panel-866` a direct descendant of an element with class .tab-title (it's not in your html sample)? If it is a child, but not a direct child, then remove the `>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the inline styles, which have higher [specificity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) than external / embedded styles.

Try this:

```
#panel-866 > .application-icon:hover { 
    background-image:url('/custom-icon-hover.png') !important;
}
```

Here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/0aghvn3u/

Answer (score 0):

The '>' - selector gets direct descendants, maybe just remove

```
.tab-title >
```

and it will work. Difficult to say without knowing your markup since its a simple task and your solution seems to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Make it important so it overrides the anchor tag's default hover styles.

```
.tab-title > #panel-866 .application-icon:hover {
    background-image:url('/custom-icon-hover.png') !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code, so it's hard to say what specifically is causing the problem. You have a `div` element in an `a` tag, which you should avoid because block level elements don't work well within inline elements. This is likely not the problem, though.

I've added some markup and removed some CSS that included a selector not in the code you presented here that might have caused the effect not to work:

```
<a href="#panel-866" id="panel-866">
    <span class="application-icon" style="background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/400')">
        &nbsp;
    </span>
</a>
```

and

```
#panel-866 .application-icon {
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    display: block;
}

#panel-866 .application-icon:hover {
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/400) !important;
}
```

Notice I made the inline span element `display:block` (this is technically "allowed") so I could give it a width and height. Even when on a `div` element, background images need a width and height to display.

Secondly, as the other posters mentioned, adding an !important declaration to your `:hover` style rule is needed because browsers will always override internal or external style rules with inline ones.

https://jsfiddle.net/3b2ywp5b/

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It's the most comprehensive answer on here.